# How to change input type of sap.ui.input control. I have done as per documentation but it is not reflecting in view

Tags: input, sapui5

I want to change input type from password to text.

What i have done:

1) In xml view:

```
<input type="Password" id="idPassword" showValueHelp="true" /> // enabling showValueHelp a button right corner in input text
```

2) In controller :

```
var oInput = this.getView().byId("idPassword"); 
oInput.attachValueHelpRequest(function(){
oInput.type = "Text"; //change input type as per documentation. 
console.log(oInput); // I can see type="Text" in console  
});
```

Actually It is not reflecting in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not method called `type`.You should use

```
oInput.setType("Text");
```

or

```
oInput.setType(sap.m.InputType.Text);
```

Note:default type is Text.So you dont have to set it at all

Comment: "type" is property of sap.m.input control. Yes, default is "Text". I am trying to change it from "Password" to "Text" when user click on help indicator.